# PassportLocalDocument and PaginateModel on the same interface?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am relatively new to typescript and NestJS framework. Currently I would like to implement a pagination mechanism for all models in my application. In the current api project I am using NestJS with mongoose.

My user schemma is the following

```
export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  password: {
    type: String
  }
});

UserSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
  usernameField: 'email',
});
```

My user interface is the following:

```
export interface IUser extends PassportLocalDocument {
  readonly firstName: string;
  readonly lastName: string;
  readonly email: string;
  readonly phone: string;
  readonly password: string;
}
```

And my userService is the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService implements IUsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: PassportLocalModel<IUser>) {
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<IUser[]> {
    return await this.userModel.find().exec();
  }
```

I would like to add the mongoose-paginate functionality trough my IUser interface, so i can access it in the service via `this.userModel.paginate`.

I mention that I installed : `"@types/mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.6"` and `"mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3"`, and I can import `PaginateModel` from `mongoose`.

I guess the `IUser` interface should look something like this :

`export interface IUser<T extends PassportLocalDocument > extends PaginateModel<T> {}` but I am not sure, nor how to instantiate it when injecting into service.

Waiting ur responses guys, and Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached the situation in a different matter. I've created 2 interfaces, 1 for registration/authentication and the other for data manipulation.

Once u import the PaginateModel you have to extend your interface with `Document`.

`export interface IUser extends Document`

Afterwards when you inject it into your service:

`@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: PaginateModel<IUser>`

And finally, in your service interface and service implementation, change the return type like this:

`async findAll(yourParams: YourParamsDto): Promise<PaginateResult<IUser>>`

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet for those who are using [mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate) plugin with nestjs. You can also install [@types/mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose-paginate) for getting the typings support

1. Code for adding the paginate plugin to the schema:

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';

export const MessageSchema = new Schema({
// Your schema definitions here
});

// Register plugin with the schema
MessageSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

2. Now in the Message interface document

```
export interface Message extends Document {
// Your schema fields here
}
```

3. Now you can easily get the paginate method inside the service class like so

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { PaginateModel } from 'mongoose';
import { Message } from './interfaces/message.interface';

@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {
    constructor(
        // The 'PaginateModel' will provide the necessary pagination methods
        @InjectModel('Message') private readonly messageModel: PaginateModel<Message>,
    ) {}

    /**
     * Find all messages in a channel
     *
     * @param {string} channelId
     * @param {number} [page=1]
     * @param {number} [limit=10]
     * @returns
     * @memberof MessagesService
     */
    async findAllByChannelIdPaginated(channelId: string, page: number = 1, limit: number = 10) {
        const options = {
            populate: [
                // Your foreign key fields to populate
            ],
            page: Number(page),
            limit: Number(limit),
        };
        // Get the data from database
        return await this.messageModel.paginate({ channel: channelId }, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Totoro this has to do with your tsconfig, as this feature used to work in the earlier version of the application. Recent updates to the tsconfig configurations causes this problem i suppose.